# Why does org.apache.poi.hssf give wrong color with Excel 2007?

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007

Why does org.apache.poi.hssf give the wrong color a cell which with Excel 2007? With the 2010 version there are no problem.

Any idea for a fix/workaround?

```
 final HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
 final HSSFColor backgroundColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
 String theColor = ExcelToHtmlUtils.getColor( backgroundColor );
```

I  tried couple libraries but no luck. Only xlsgen gives good results but it is not open source, which I would prefer.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful.  Does the excel file you are reading from have a custom palette?  What color is the cell, what color is it telling you it is?

Comment: the color of cell is "Light green", no custom palette and in result it gives me "yellow"

Comment: what i found, OpenOffice also gives yellow on cells with light green in Ecxel 2007

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I notice: you seem to want the background color, but you instead ask for the `FillForegroundColorColor`. I think you want to do this instead:

```
final HSSFColor backgroundColor = cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
```

Try that instead and let us know.